# Different definitions of ring of sets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am studying measure theory now and I have encountered three different definitions of ring of sets (from different sources), here is the list of them:

1. $\mathcal{R}$ is called ring of sets if $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ implies $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R};$
2. $\mathcal{R}$ is called ring of sets if $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ implies $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}\setminus\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R};$
3. $\mathcal{R}$ is called ring of sets if $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ implies $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}\;\triangle\;\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R};$

It was easy for me to prove that the $2$ and the $3$ are equivalent (if we have $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}\setminus\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ than we have $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}\;\triangle\;\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{R}$ and vice versa), however, it seems like the $1$ isn't to them. From standard identities of set theory it looks like using only $\cap, \cup$ we can't obtain $\triangle, \setminus$. But I have problem in providing more strict proof.

May be there are some examples of collection of sets which satisfy the $1$ definition but not the $2$ (or vice versa)? Or may be there is some general proof?

Comment: A collection of sets that is totally ordered by $\subseteq$ satisfies (1), but it hardly ever satisfies (2). On the other hand, (2) implies (1) because $A\cap B=A\setminus(A\setminus B)$.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets). The first definition is not for measure theory; it's for order theory. There is no suggestion that the order theoretic definition and the measure theoretic definition are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry this is a answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment)

To my understanding the first definition is used in order theory and the later in measure theory